# Use capture group when \K construct

Tags: regex, perl

I'm playing around with the \K construct during a substitution operation, but it appears that capture groups aren't available to the right side.

**Code:**

```
my $string = 'lowerupper';
$string =~ s/lower\K(\w+)/\U$1/;
print $string;
```

**Output:**

```
lowerupper
```

**Expected Output:**

```
lowerUPPER
```

Why is this / is it possible to achieve the above without capturing 'lower'.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: There is no reason this doesn't work, `\K` does not change the behaviour of anything. Works well for me. Check your code.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I am testing using codepad.org running Perl version 5.008 (`print $];`). I assume \K hadn't been introduced.

Comment: Indeed, the `\K` has been introduced since the 5.10 version. Thus the reason you didn't obtain the result is that your pattern didn't match the string.

Comment: An other possibility to not capture "lower" is to use a lookbehind: `(?<=lower)(\w+)`

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, thanks for the alternative. Worth noting though that my actual regexp uses a variable length string before \K.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid capturing `lower`? You have the performance penalty of having captures with or without capturing `lower`.

Comment: @ikegami, I wasn't aware that there would inherently be a performance penalty. I'm just experimenting with \K, I won't necessarily use as above.

Comment: @Chris, That's why `$&` is discouraged: It forces every match in the interpreter to suffer the penalty of captures, even if it does no capturing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change isn't occurring because the pattern doesn't match because you are using a version of Perl that predates the addition of `\K`. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

With 5.8,

```
$ perl -wle'
   my $string = "lowerupper";
   $string =~ s/lower\K(\w+)/\U$1/;
   print $string;
'
Unrecognized escape \K passed through at -e line 3.
lowerupper
```

With 5.10+,

```
$ perl -wle'
   my $string = "lowerupper";
   $string =~ s/lower\K(\w+)/\U$1/;
   print $string;
'
lowerUPPER
```

You can obtain the result you want using

```
s/(lower)(\w+)/$1\U$2/;
```

and

```
s/(?<=lower)(\w+)/\U$1/;
```

The first is probably a little more efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. I had a script composed of lots of different snippets I had been experimenting with, laziness => bad practices throughout i.e. not declaring vars => turn off strict / warnings!

Comment: Not using `use strict; use warnings;` just silences the errors messages; it doesn't make the errors go away.

Comment: Understood. I wouldn't possibly write serious code without including those!

Comment: As for throwaway snippets, the first thing you should do when you can't explain an error is to stop silencing the errors.

Comment: I will definitely from now on. Just to dispute your logic though, if the error is silent then I have nothing to explain ;).

Comment: You came here, so that's not true.

Comment: I assumed there was no error, I wanted to understand why it "wasn't possible" / wanted an alternative solution. I totally understand what you inferred though, an error doesn't have to be in the form of a message.

Comment: @Chris, Then you appear to have a different definition of error than I do. I consider not getting the expected outcome to be on error.

Comment: I agree. My point hasn't come across well.