# How to use capture groups with the `\K` reset match?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24610423/5252007) about using capture groups with the `\K` reset match (i.e., not sure if that's the correct name), but it does not answer my query.

Suppose I have the following string:

```markdown
ab
```

With the following `regex` `a\Kb` the output is, as expected, `b`:

[image]

However, when adding a capture group (i.e., `$1`) using the `regex` `(a\Kb)`, group `$1` returns `ab` and not `a`:

[image]

Given the following string:

```markdown
ab
cd
```

Using the `regex` `(a\Kb)|(c\Kd)` I would hope group `$1` to contain `b` and group `$2` to contain `d`, but that is not the case as it can be seen below:

[image]

I tried [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)'s answer that points to using a [*branch reset group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```regex
(?|a\Kb)|(?|c\Kd)
```

Which produces:

[image]

However, now the matches are both part of group `$0`, whereas I require them to be part of group `$1` and `$2`, respectively. Do you have any ideas on how this can be achieved? I am using [Oniguruma regular expressions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-grammars) and the [`PCRE`](https://www.pcre.org) flavor.

---

**Update based on the comments below.**

The example above was meant to be easy to understand and reproduce.
[@Booboo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823719/booboo) pointed out that a *non-capturing group* does the trick, i.e.,:

```regex
(?:a\K(b))|(?:c\K(d))
```

Produce the output:

[image]

However, when applied to another example it fails. Therefore, for clarity, I am extending this question to cover the more complicated scenario discussed in the comments.

Suppose I have the following text in a `markdown` file:

```markdown
- [x] Example task. | Task ends. [x] Another task.
- [x] ! Example task. | This ends. [x] ! Another task.

This is a sentence. [x] Task is here.
Other text. Another [x] ! Task is here.

|       | Task name     |    Plan     |   Actual    |      File      |
| :---- | :-------------| :---------: | :---------: | :------------: |
| [x]   | Task example. | 08:00-08:45 | 08:00-09:00 |  [[task-one]]  |
| [x] ! | Task example. | 08:00-08:45 | 08:00-09:00 |  [[task-one]]  |
```

I am interested in a single `regex` expression with **two capture groups** as follows:

- group `$1` (i.e., see selection below):

  - outside the table: capture everything after `[x]` (i.e., not followed by `!`) until a `|`
  - inside the table: capture everything after `[x]` (i.e., not followed by `!`) excluding the `|` symbols

    [image: Matches for first capture group]
- group `$2` (i.e., see selection below):

  - outside the table: capture everything after `[x] !` until a `|`
  - inside the table: capture everything after `[x] !` excluding the `|` symbols

    [image: Mataches for the second capture group]

I have the following `regex` (i.e., [see demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iBu8r9/1)) that works when evaluated individually, but not when used inside a capture group:

- group `$1`:

  - outside the table: `[^\|\s]\s*\[x\]\s*\K[^!|\n]*`
  - inside the table: `(?:\G(?!\A)\||(?<=\[x]\s)\s*\|)\K[^|\n]*(?=\|)`
- group `$2`:

  - outside the table: `[^\|\s]\s*\[x\]\s*\!\s*\K[^|\n]*`
  - inside the table: `(?:\G(?!\A)\||(?<=\[x]\s)\s*\!\s*\|)\K[^|\n]*(?=\|)`

The problem I am experiencing is when combining the expressions above.

Pseudo `regex`:

```regex
([x] outside|[x] inside)|([x] ! outside|[x] ! inside)
```

Actual `regex`:

```regex
([^\|\s]\s*\[x\]\s*\K[^!|\n]*|(?:\G(?!\A)\||(?<=\[x]\s)\s*\|)\K[^|\n]*(?=\|))|([^\|\s]\s*\[x\]\s*\!\s*\K[^|\n]*|(?:\G(?!\A)\||(?<=\[x]\s)\s*\!\s*\|)\K[^|\n]*(?=\|))
```

Which produces (i.e., as in the [demo linked above](https://regex101.com/r/iBu8r9/1)):

[image]

The `regex` for the matches inside the table is based on [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)'s answer and [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70225240/5252007).

Comment: Why not just use a *lookbehind assertion* instead: `((?<=a)b)`. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eq64HM/1/)

Comment: @Booboo, my actual pattern is more complicated than the MRE in the question (e.g.,  https://regex101.com/r/mQl58d/1) and I am not sure I can do it with a *lookbehind*...

Comment: @Booboo, I think the reason why I cannot use a *positive lookbehind* assertion is because of the fixed-width restriction.

Comment: Anyway, perhaps Mr. Stribiżew will see this and chime in. You should also tag your question with the language you are using. Interesting that it supports \K but not varying length lookbehinds.

Comment: And you would not be happy with `(?:a\K(b))` ? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/orLW3F/1/)

Comment: @Booboo, thanks, I'll go ahead and tag it. I am using the `PCRE2` flavour and the `regex` in question is for a [grammar language injection in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-grammars).

Comment: @Booboo, ha! The `(?:a\K(b))|(?:c\K(d))` seems to do the trick (e.g., [`regex` demo](https://regex101.com/r/TnZkru/1). But why?

Comment: (?: blah-blah) is a *non-capturing* group. So there is only a single *capturing* group, namely capture group 1, in my regex.

Comment: @Booboo, that makes sense. Yet, I just tried it for the more complicated example and it fails (e.g., [`regex` demo](https://regex101.com/r/0OcU2q/1)). Sorry for the back and forth, but appreciate your input.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, maybe something like that: https://regex101.com/r/L6C6UL/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I apologize for the confusion. I wanted to only provide an MRE but that backfired... I updated the question to reflect what I really am after.

Comment: If you are sure there's always a horizontal space at the end of each cells, you can eventually do that: https://regex101.com/r/1o4OyE/2

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I carefully studied your solution and I think it fits the bill. I want to test a few more cases and I will report back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?|(?:\G(?!\A)(?<=\|)|^\|\h*\[x\]\h*\|)\h*\K([^|\n]+)(?<=\S)\h*\||\[x]\h*\K([^|\s!]+(?:\h*[^|\s]+)*))|(?|(?:\G(?!\A)\||^\|\h*\[x]\h*!\h*\|)\h*\K([^|\n]+)(?<=\S)\h*|\[x]\h*!\h*\K([^|\s]+(?:\h*[^|\s]+)*))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VIaHZW/1). *Details*:

- `(?|(?:\G(?!\A)(?<=\|)|^\|\h*\[x\]\h*\|)\h*\K([^|\n]+)(?<=\S)\h*\||\[x]\h*\K([^|\s!]+(?:\h*[^|\s]+)*))` - a branch reset group matching:

  - `(?:\G(?!\A)(?<=\|)|^\|\h*\[x\]\h*\|)` - a non-capturing group matching either

    - `\G(?!\A)(?<=\|)` - the end of the previous successful match that is immediately preceded with a `|` char
  - `|` - or

    - `^\|\h*\[x\]\h*\|` - start of a line/string, `|`, zero or more horizontal whitespaces, `[x]`, zero or more horizontal whitespaces, `|`
  - `\h*\K` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces that are immediately discarded from the match value after matching
  - `([^|\n]+)(?<=\S)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than a LF and `|`, as many as possible, but the chunk should match with a non-whitespace char
  - `\h*\|` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces and a `|` char
- `|` - or

  - `\[x]\h*\K` - `[x]`, zero or more horizontal whitespaces, and this text is discarded from the match value
  - `([^|\s!]+(?:\h*[^|\s]+)*)` - Group 1 (mind it is a branch reset group): one or more chars other than `!`, `|` and whitespace, and then zero or more occurrences of zero or more horizontal whitespaces and then one or more chars other than `|` and whitespace
- `|` - or
- `(?|(?:\G(?!\A)\||^\|\h*\[x]\h*!\h*\|)\h*\K([^|\n]+)(?<=\S)\h*|\[x]\h*!\h*\K([^|\s]+(?:\h*[^|\s]+)*))` - a branch reset group:

  - `(?:\G(?!\A)\||^\|\h*\[x]\h*!\h*\|)` - end of the previous successful match and a `|` char after, or start of string, `|`, zero or more horizontal whitespaces, `[x]`, `!` enclosed with zero or more horizontal whitespaces, a `|` char
  - `\h*\K` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces and the whole text matched so far is discarded from the match value
  - `([^|\n]+)(?<=\S)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than LF and `|` chars that end with a non-whitespace char
  - `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `|` - or

  - `\[x]` - a `[x]` string
  - `\h*!\h*\K` - `!` enclosed with zero or more horizontal whitespaces and the whole text matched so far is discarded from the match value
  - `([^|\s]+(?:\h*[^|\s]+)*)` - Group 2 (mind it is a branch reset group): one or more chars other than `|` and whitespace, and then zero or more occurrences of zero or more horizontal whitespaces and then one or more chars other than `|` and whitespace.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to accomplish! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I've learned a lot from you these past few days.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\K`, try to use control verbs [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex):

```
(a(*SKIP)(*F)|b)|(c(*SKIP)(*F)|d)
```

Check the [test case](https://regex101.com/r/uRv382/1/).

Comment: This is very interesting! I will experiment around with these verbs in the more complicated example and report back!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to match, use as a regex:

```
(?:[^|\s]\s*\[x\](?!\s*!)\s*\K([^!|\n]*))|(?:[^|\s]\s*\[x\]\s*!\s*\K([^|\n]*))
```

See [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L8gtR9/1/)

I removed some unnecessary escaping. But moreover:

For Group 1 matches (first alternative) before the `|`, note that I have after we have matched '[x]` the following negative lookahead assertion:

```
(?!\s*!)
```

This ensures that the [x] is not followed by 0 or more spaces followed by an exclamation mark. Only then do you want to match everything up to the next exclamation mark or newline as Group 1.

Comment: As I also said above, I apologize for the confusion. I wanted to only provide an MRE but that may have not been a wise choice. I updated my question to be as clear as possible about the intended outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the example you've provided on regex101 the following expression can be tried, with one caveat, the text should not not contain any third bracket other than "[x]"

```
(?<!\|\s)(((?:\[x]\s[!]?))\K[^[\n]+)
```

Explaining the above

> 1. `(?<!\|\s)`

- This negative lookahead will discard the table, as you mentioned

> 2. (?:[x]\s[!]?)

- This is a Non-Capturing group that will match "[x] " or "[x] !"

> 3. \K (Optional)

- \K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

> 4. [^[\n]+

- negative match the previous token between one and unlimited times.

[Regex101 sample](https://regex101.com/r/FdEkIS/1)

Comment: Please try out and tell. Do check on the mentioned caveat

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I tried it (e.g., [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/UvZudU/1)), but it doesn't match the requirements. I added a more detailed description in the demo linked above about what each group should capture. The closest I got is in [this demo here](https://regex101.com/r/4dJVlz/6).

Comment: Added [ to the list of tokens at which to stop matching. Side effect is the text in the table with [[task name]] https://regex101.com/r/QUWUEK/1.